# Can I install python 3.6.1 and 3.6.3 together?

Tags: python

Is it possible to install patch updated versions of python on the same system?  For example 3.6.1 and 3.6.3 together.

For example, 3.6 and 3.7 can be installed no problem.  But I am wondering about the patch versions (3.6.1 and 3.6.2, etc.).  This didn't work using the regular Windows installer.  I would like to be able to have both so I can test code against different python bases using virtual environment.

Comment: Try [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: I'm not sure *why* you would want or need two different versions of 3.6 installed, but yes, it's no different than installing 3.6 and 3.7 side-by-side on the same machine.

Comment: Yes, the 3.6 and 3.7 can be installed no problem.  I am wondering about the patch versions (3.6.1 vs 3.6.2, etc.).  I would like to be able to have both so I can test code against different python bases using virtual environment.

Comment: The version numbers don't really matter. The key is that Python installations are distinct from each other; they don't share any code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Take a look at installing Python [using PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) and you should be able to install various versions of Python on the same system.